# CloudWatch Logs Group By and getting last time value

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

*I need to map which endpoints are taking the longest from a log.*

I have a query that catches all the most discouraged endpoints, but they may have duplicate endpoints, but with different request times.

**My query:**

```
fields request.url as URL, response.content.manager.company.label as Empresa, timestamp as Data, response.status as Status, request.time as TEMPO
| filter @logStream = 'production'
| sort request.time DESC
| limit 30
```

**Result:**

# | **ENDPOINT** | **TIMESTAMP** | **COMPANY**  | **STATUS CODE** | **TIME REQUEST**
1 | **/api/v1/login** | **2020-02-01T11:14:00** | company-label | 200 | 0.9876
2 | /api/v1/register | 2020-02-01T11:11:00 | company-label | 200 | 0.5687
3 | /api/v1/login | 2020-02-01T00:00:00 | company-label | 200 | 0.2345\

I need to unify by endpoint, for **example**:
# | **ENDPOINT** | **TIMESTAMP** | **COMPANY**  | **STATUS CODE** | **TIME REQUEST**
1 | **/api/v1/login** | **2020-02-01T11:14:00** | company-label | 200 | 0.9876
2 | /api/v1/register | 2020-02-01T11:11:00 | company-label | 200 | 0.5687\

Unify by endpoint and get the last "time" to show

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this question.

```
filter @logStream = 'production'
| filter ispresent(request.time)
| stats avg(request.time) as MEDIA by request.uri as ENDPOINT
| sort MEDIA DESC
| limit 30
```

Using the `stats avg(request.time) as MEDIA` to grouping data and capture an media to this **ENDPOINT**.